# Windows Upgrade vs Full Install

Tags: windows, upgrade

I'm in the process of purchasing a Netbook for use while traveling. The included OS is XP, however, I would like to upgrade(?) to Windows 7.

My question: Does a Windows Upgrade have the same physical footprint and performance as a full install? Does an upgrade leave behind non used files/resources that were originally included in XP? If so, are there ways to reduce this?

I'm trying to reduce as much OS bloat as possible.

Please let me know if my question is unclear. Thanks.

Related to [Is a clean install really better than an upgrade?](https://superuser.com/questions/60646/is-a-clean-install-really-better-than-an-upgrade) however, this doesn't address the "leftovers" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upgrade path from XP to 7 isn't supported, you will **have to** do a full install regardless. But in terms of compatible upgrade paths, an upgrade will leave behind some clutter.

If you want a fresh, clean slate, always go for the full install.

Comment: Ouch, thanks for the feedback John. Pretty much narrows my options down. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 Clean install is always the best route if you can.  No leftovers and you control what options are installed.