# windows 8 upgrade to 10 performance of upgrade vs full install

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

So my question is more around this  [Windows Upgrade vs Full Install](https://superuser.com/questions/79981/windows-upgrade-vs-full-install). Obviously if you have only been given the option to upgrade via a web interface then it isn't possible to do a full install since you don't have a actual OS to hand to install from.

I presume same rules apply that an upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 10 will not work as well as a full install of windows 10.  I am only asking since the performance on my machine has massively degraded since upgrade.

So I just wanted to fully summarise my conclusion of upgrades, Pre doing the upgrade I had a suspicion that there may be a loss in performance based on when I did upgrades during a period when more actively using windows more specifically 95/XP. The provided question seems to suggest it is a known factor from ages back, so it would be safe to assume MS are also aware of this too.

My entire point of raising this question was really to highlight as pointed on my comment that it was a web upgrade, it was given a limited window before offer expired. Whilst it reminded me of the great offer, it failed to mention this aspect. I am not having a moan this is really a suggestion. If something is proven not to be good as the real thing, surely you are leaving a bad taste in the user's mouth.

I think it would be useful to provide end user looking to upgrade with a chart showing a comparison study done internally comparing an upgrade vs a full install. This way it is to show to possibly others saying to upgrade that I choose not to based on the results shown here.

Ultimately a full install means wiping slate and starting again which in short I feel if correct information had been given I may have been happier on 8.1.

I am good at expressing my opinion and there maybe many others who wish to express this and can't find a way to do so. I hope people don't treat this in a negative way. This is meant to be a positive feed back to improve product

Comment: Anytime you can manage it, I would recommend a full install simply because it avoids many possible problems you will face with an upgrade.

Comment: As the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/79984/690483) says on that question you linked: `An upgrade will leave behind some clutter. If you want a fresh, clean slate, always go for the full install.` A clean install will always be better, from a performance standpoint.

Comment: right and if you only had an option to upgrade via a web link no cd no usb stick and all you have is the old OS :) then a clean install of 8.1 ?. It sounds like of all the users took this option and they want maximum performance without the actual OS having been sent to them as part of upgrade then it's a case of purchasing 10. I ceeeeeee nice

Comment: There is no difference between an upgrade where you choose to keep nothing and a clean install of Windows 10. This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/79981/windows-upgrade-vs-full-install/79984#79984) is wrong with regards to the clutter

Answer (score 1):

The comments confirm your experience: an upgrade *may* leave you with a less performant system compared to a clean install. You seem to complain about being given no choice, so here's a solution.

What several people did when offered the web upgrade was to:

1. make a backup
2. grab a Windows 10 ISO (apparently, it can be found and it is leagel and free to download it) and create an installation media (DVD or USB stick)
3. do the web upgrade
4. get the Windows product key with the help of some free utility
5. perform a clean Windows 10 installation (blanking the hard drive) using the media they created and the product key they extracted
6. restore their files from the backup

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is of great help. I don't claim to be an expert in windows OS matters. Advice would obviously cure any hitches around performance. I think even with steps if i were a super novice user I probably endure performance over technicality. Anyhow I am simply stating the obvious and what seems common sense. If to experience something brand new provided in a limited time frame, if user doesn't upgrade they may feel they lost out vs they upgrade and get brand new but not optimal performance and to get optimal involves wipes slate. Either way user may feel loose/loose :)

Comment: If you're saying customers should be given the choice of upgrading or reinstalling and at the same time be properly informed about advantages and drawbacks of either solution, I agree. Luckily, there are workarounds and informative forums.

Comment: Absolutely what I am saying. In short all of those workarounds/informative forums could be wrapped up in a nice pdf illustrating performance of a full vs upgrade with the upgrade notification - This way if as an employee you feel it is probably best but someone above who may not be looking at the informative forums or aware of such things could take a decision. Lots of then upgraded people facing slow down. If i eat at a restaurant and I don't like it I don't think I would go back. So to leave a bitter taste on latest and greatest well it just leaves food for thought not mouth :)

Comment: I like your restaurant comparison. Good news is, you don't have to go back (pick your choice of Linux distribution).