# Windows (7, 8, 10) - Is a clean install better than an upgrade and if so why? (be specific)

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-10

I'd like to know if given an existing Windows PC, are there any concrete reasons why a clean install should be performed over an update.

Articles like [this one at How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/142743/htg-explains-why-you-should-perform-clean-installs-not-upgrades/) refer to "bloatware" and "clutter" on the PC and rightly suggest that this might not be something that you want on the upgraded PC. [This post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/60646/is-a-clean-install-really-better-than-an-upgrade) refers to "crashes" and upgrades being "problematic". Both are fairly non specific as to what these problems might be though.

If I'm happy that there is no bloatware or clutter on the PC prior to the upgrade, are there any *specific* known issues that can cause *specific* problems when upgrading rather than clean installing?

Or is it just a case of being sure?

Comment: Clean install can be done, but you have to upgrade first, activate the installation, [then do a clean install](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/07/how-to-do-a-clean-install-of-windows-10-from-windows-7-and-8/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the free upgrade of Windows 10 to apply, you NEED to upgrade. Its as simple as that. This will bring you your settings with you, and best of all, because it will install new system components, the entire windows framework will be new (errors from the past will be fixed)

I had a problem on one of my pc's where windows update was broken. I used the offline upgrade tool to upgrade that particular pc and windows update is fixed again. yay.

Once you upgraded to windows 10, you can use the buildin functionality to make it go to a clean state from whitin windows 10. This will allow you to start fresh which will help get your windows back to speed if it was terribly slow in the past. It will keep windows 10 installed, just remove everything (you can select what to keep) and go on from there. Doing a clean-up this way will also remove any bloatware. Windows framework is already new from the upgrade, and the clean will remove any infections related to the files you had unless you choose to keep those.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted the reset functionality in Windows 10. (Appears it was there in Windows 8 too, but didn't use Windows 8 much).

Comment: Oh I actually didn't know it was also present in Windows 8. XD good to know. :)

Answer (score -2):

Actually pretty simple. 
With an update you could drag a preexisting error with you.
With a clean install, you can't drag a preexisting error with you.

I am not a huge fan of clean install. I usually advise against. You can still clean install your system when something went wrong.

Windows 10 hasn't been rolled out for me, but I do have experience with slow systems and most systems you can clean up. I had the case in which a MacBook was extremely slow after restoring it from a backup Mavericks and updating it to Yosemite. After removing unnecessary application, emptying out startup folders, emptying caches, repairing the file system, etc., the system was up and running. So, whenever you decide to have a clean install, you should be sure to have done everything that you can or time and necessity allows. Otherwise you will be condemned to periodic reinstalls and constant slowing computers.

Actually, a computer should be running stable for a long time with weekly reboots. This is true for all of the major operation systems. So, for learning purposes and future fun with your computer, don't clean install unless it's unavoidable.

Comment: I'm voting this down because with Windows 10 this information is not correct. (or at least it gives problems if you go to it this way.)

Comment: down voting is alright. but please elaborate. where am I wrong?

Comment: First of, you don't have experience with windows 10, so this is speculation. Secondly, you state a computer should be running stable for a long time with weekly reboots. Besides this being your opinion, its not really related to the question. And lastly, you start with: An upgrade could drag preexisting errors with you, where a clean install doesn't. This would suggest you should do a clean install, something that is not possible with windows 10 as the free upgrade works totally different, but given that you don't have windows 10 yet, you miss the experience. This all lead me to downvote.

Comment: 1. Dragging preexisting errors is definitely true. My answer is based, that there are advantages of updating that are more important. 
2. Win 10 can be clean installed. After you've upgraded, you can create a flash drive and install it again. Upgrade has only to be performed once.
3. My last point is, that an operation system is designed to work stable. No one has the experience of a long time running Win 10 system. Yet, we do have empiric evidence with similar systems, including Win 8. Should Win 10 not be capable of sustaining a long term OS, than this is a bug that we can't know yet.

Comment: Your answer does not reflect this knowledge, which is my point. Mine does so yes, I am aware of the procedure. Also you do not need the flash medium for the clean slate install. You can directly do this from windows 10 through the start menu.

Comment: Also, you can force the installation by going here: http://microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: If you take another look at the question, this question was not solely related to Win10. It also has 8 or 7 in there. And it is asking not about any specific methods of a clean install, but if it is necessary and if you should do this. Your answer doesn't address this question. It mainly describes how it is done. It doesn't address if it is a good idea. You only say, it makes a slow computer fast again. We still haven't weighed this method against any other less invasive maintenance. Yet, I simply wanted to state why I think this down vote is undeserved. I leave it with that. We do disagree.